# solving the recursion T(n)=log(T(n-1))+1

Tags: function, recursion

I'm trying to solve this recursion:

```
                            T(n)=log(T(n-1))+1    :n>2
                            T(n)=O(1)             :n=2
```

I'm getting an answer of O(1), but I feel I'm missing something.

I'd be happy to get some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any limitations on `n`? Should it be greater that `0` or what? Where is your code?

Comment: Thank you I edited the post.

Comment: It's still unclear what you asking. There is no code which indicates that you even trying! `T(n)=O(1)             :n=2` what is that? `T(2) = O(1)` what???

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about writing code. Your question is off topic here. I would recommend moving it to the [Computer Science Stack Exchange Site](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) It is also a bit vague so you may want to review their [policy on asking questions](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Your recursion relation converges to 1.0 for any value >= 1.0

Your answer of **O**(1) is quite correct.  You may be a little thrown by the recursion relation being expressed in such a straightforward fashion of time, rather than being given the algorithm?

---

Let me try again.  Also, perhaps we're both a little confused.  I answered at the single-call level; perhaps you need the overall answer (more likely, now that I think about it).

First, let's take a single call.  If n=2, it's constant time.  If n>2 ... this is where I'm not quite familiar with the notation.  Does this denote time for a *single* call, or for the entire recursion sequence descending to n=2?  I think it has to be for the single call, due to practical considerations.  This makes my earlier answer incorrect.

Look at the call for n=3.  This expands and solves as

```
T(3) = log(T(2)) + 1
T(3) = log(1) + 1
T(3) = 0 + 1 = 1
```

By induction T(n) = 1 for n >= 2.  As it turns out, even if the base case -- T(2) -- has a value other than 1, so long as it's finite and more than 1/ (whatever base we're using for logs), the series will converge to 1, and each call will be in constant time.

Thus, to solve T(n), we have n-2 calls, each of which is T(1).  This gives an overall complexity of **O(n)**.

Is that more clear?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. though, the solution still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the expansion. From your explanation, I understand by induction that:
if T(n-1)=1 then
T(n)=log(T(n-1))+1=log(1)+1=1. so T(n)=O(1).
which seems isn't right for me.
maybe T(n-1)=c, when c is some constant, and then: 
T(n)=log(T(n-1)+1=log(c)+1 
which is not equal to O(1)?